# ATTINYx5 usi for uart?

Tags: softwareserial, attiny, uart

Can the ATTINYx5 use its universal serial interface for a better UART than the Sofware Serial library alone? If so, is there a library or tutorial for this?

Comment: An answer got deleted. Spooky. (it was about the hardware Serial lib)

Comment: Here is a [receive only USI UART](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?VSX) for the ATtinyX5 and ATtinyX4.

Answer (score 1):

[AVR307](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4300.pdf) describes implementation of a half duplex UART implementation using the USI. Note that full duplex is not possible due to the synchronous design of the USI.

Comment: That implementation uses `ISR(TIMER0_OVF)` to clock bits in and out. This is not needed on the ATtinyX5, since you will clock the USI from TIM0\_COMPA and set timer0 to CTC mode instead of periodically reloading the seed.